# css3 inset shadow with tab effect

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to figure out how to create a tab like effect while using CSS3 inset shadows.

Here's my attempt: http://beta.songdesk.com/home/tour/overview

And here's what it needs to look like:

http://beta.songdesk.com/img/tab-box-shadow-page.png

Answer (score 1):

In short, what you're trying to achieve here can't be done, since you're dealing with separate boxes, not with one single polygons.

One could do a **lot** of trickery with additional, overlayed divs and other stuff, but it would clutter the markup and be very hard to get right / maintain.

You might want to use a [border image](http://www.css3.info/preview/border-image/) instead, this might still involve some trickery but it should be easier to get a consistent look across browsers.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of.  I'm not sure how using the border image helps though, wouldn't I run into the same issues as using the box-shadow?  Thanks for your reply!

Comment: I ended up making it work with an overlayed div using an image to cover up the unwanted shadows.  It adds a little bit of unwanted markup but it's really only one div, so I call that a success.